# AutoComplete with ForEach loop in jsf is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

am using primefaces for my project. I am facing issue while using autocomplete inside  loop.
inside forEach loop i have an outputlabel and an autocomplete tag. I mapped "items" attribute in forEach loop to an HashMap and according to the map size the loop is iterated and outputlabel and autocomplete are rendered.
The output label is rendered sequentially but the autocomplete is rendered in same position(overlapping eachother).

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div style="margin-top: 2.3%;">
  <c:forEach var="attachMap" items="#{searchAccountBean.attachmentMap}">
    <h:outputText style="margin-top:4%" value="#{attachMap.key}"></h:outputText>
      <p:autoComplete value="#{searchAccountBean.attachmentMap[attachMap.key]}"
        id="autoId_#{attachMap.key}" 
   completeMethod="#{searchAccountBean.completeAccountName}"
   var="p" itemLabel="#{p}" itemValue="#{p}" forceSelection="true"
   size="15" style="margin-top:2.5%;" 
   scrollHeight="80" minQueryLength="1" title="Enter Account Name">
     <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#searchAccountBean.handleSelectAccount}"></p:ajax>
          <p:ajax event="blur"></p:ajax>
      </p:autoComplete>
      <p:spacer width="30px" ></p:spacer>
    </c:forEach>
  </div>
```

Comment: i posted code, its not showing.. tell me how to post code here..

Comment: See the hints to the right of the edit box. 4 spaces and occasionally a block quote with >. I've made the code visible; you'd probably want to format it more.

Comment: Why are you using c:forEach, and not ui:repeat, in first line?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech ok i'l try with ui:repeat, but my problem is with autocomplete. when ever i use two or more autocomplete, they are overlapping in UI, i need to move each autocomplete using margin-left to make each one visible sequentially.

Comment: @AndersUP Thanks for making my code visible.. :)

Comment: @PraveenPrime You're welcome. And welcome to SO. :)